# How do I get a UIImage from an image file on my server?

Tags: iphone, uikit, asynchronous, uiimage

How do I get a `UIImage` from a small image file on my server (can be `.jpg` or `.png`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString* url = @"http://my.server.com/image.png";
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

See also:

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:]
```